# Compiler error: unmatched call to pow(...)

Tags: c++, porting, x86-64

My company has a piece of software, sporting a rather large codebase. Recently I was assigned the task of checking wether the code would compile on an x86_64 target using gcc 4.1.2. I've gotten pretty far in the compilation with very minor modifications to the code but just this morning I got a somewhat confusing compile error.

The code is trying, and failing, to call `pow`from `<cmath>` using `int, unsigned int&` as parameters. The compiler spits out an error because it can't find a suitable match to call. The overloads for `pow` in `<cmath>` are as follows:

```
double pow(double base, double exponent)
long double pow(long double base, long double exponent)
float pow(float base, float exponent)
double pow(double base, int exponent)
long double pow(long double base, int exponent)
```

I'm not quite shure as to why this builds on our 32-bit environments but that's beside the point right now.

My question is: how should I cast the parameters, which `pow` should I use? Thanks.

P.S. I can't change the datatype of the parameters as doing so would require too much work. My assignment is to get the code to compile, detailing any hacks I make so that later, we can go over those hacks and find proper ways do deal with them.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the exact compilation error?  And the offending lines?

Comment: can't you just cast 'unsigned int&' to int or float? try pow(a,(float)b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making many calls to `pow(int, unsigned int)` why don't you just code it by yourself? If execution speed is not an issue, it's not much work.

Otherwise, I'd use a `pow()` overload whose input parameters are guaranteed to contain your expected values, such as `pow(float, float)` or `pow(double, double)`. Anyway, I feel that making your own version could prevent problems with conversion between floating point and integer.

Comment: That's a good idea: e.g. runtime checking that the `unsigned int` actually survives a cast to `int`...

Comment: I was about to write up a good casting example, but the point made here about cast conversion errors is a good one. Writing your own pow() function is the best bet. Otherwise, just use pow((long double)a, b);

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The result will always be integer, with these types of arguments.

Depending on the expected range of the  arguments, especially the exponent, you should choose for the `float` or `double` or `long double` version.

So that would become

```
pow( (float) i, (int)ui );
```

You can find the allowed range of arguments by [solving](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+pow%28x,y%29%3C%282%2a%2a23%29+%C3%97+2%2a%2a127+with+plot) the equation pow(i,ui) < max_double.

Comment: Seems enough to me. If there are any overflows here, they were already present in the 32b version. If you want to be absolutely sure, I would recommend checking with debugger the original version to see which overload was called there.